# Increasing the playback volume of SoundPlayer Class in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, audio, volume

I have this code that was given to me a while ago: [Storing .WAV files in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706470/storing-wav-files-in-a-variable)

And it works great, but I'm wondering if there is a simple way to boost the volume in overall for my application.

Windows reports the volume is 100%, but the sound spikes are super tiny, and the sound clips are super low in volume (Compared to other things I have playing I.E Music/Movie etc)

Thanks!

Comment: Left click on the speaker icon in your tray, you should have a clickable link at the bottom of the slider entitled mixer, click that and check what the volume setting is for your system sounds.

Comment: The volume of my app is already maxed. The sounds are much louder if I play them externally for instance in VLC

Answer (score 0):

A usable application can use SendMessage to send WM_APPCOMMAND messages to the shell to launch applications. This functionality is not guaranteed to work for other types of applications, but it should meet your needs.
Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage function calls the window procedure for the specified window and does not return until the window procedure has processed the message.

To send a message and return it immediately, use SendMessageCallback or SendNotifyMessage function. To post a message to a thread's message queue and return immediately, use the PostMessage or PostThreadMessage function.
Please refer to this previous "Stack Overflow" question found below to solve your question:
[Adjusting Windows Speaker Volume VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097666/adjusting-windows-speaker-volume-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be using these lines of code below in your button which adds an Integer, (an integer is a datum of integral data type, a data type that represents some range of mathematical integers. Integral data types may be of different sizes and may or may not be allowed to contain negative values. These values can be adjusted to meet your needs. The integer below increases the volume by 10% each time the button is clicked. The global variables found on the link page to the above answer would be applied to this method. [Adjusting Windows Speaker Volume VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097666/adjusting-windows-speaker-volume-vb-net)):

Dim arr As Integer() = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
Dim i As Integer
For Each i In arr
SendMessage(Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, &H30292, APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP
* &H10000)
Next i
Thread.Sleep(2000)